# C#: is bitvector32 more efficient than bool for flags?

Tags: c#, performance, flags

A bool requires 8 bits to store a flag: true or false.  Bitvector32 allows you to store 32 flags in 32 bits.  So 32 bool flags would be 256 bits.

However...

Bitvector32 requires you to declare an integer mask for each bit you want to address.  That mask is an integer, or 32 bits -- 32 masks times 32 bits + 32 bitvector32 bits = 1056 bits for 32 flags.

What's the point of bitvector32 if the bitmasks more than offset the efficient storage of flags?

Comment: Related: [When should I use a BitVector32?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5094350/205233)

Comment: I am voting to reopen, as the question is based on a false premise, and it's not actually a matter of opinion as to what the point of `BitVector32` is.

Comment: I was quite hoping, and expecting that my understanding is flawed.  I'm not promoting an opinion, but presenting my (limited) understanding in search of a more accurate understanding.

If this question is based on a false premise, I would like to know where the error lies.  Thanks.

Comment: You have at least two false premises in your question: a `bool` type requires 32 bits in C#, not 8 bits. Also, regardless of how you store your bit flags, you will need to know _which bit_ goes with _which flag_. The `BitVector32` type does not add to this; it's the same requirement as you'd have with any bit-based flag implementation. The `BitVector32` type simply makes it more convenient to operate (and personally, I'm not convinced it's a lot more convenient...dealing with bit flags isn't that hard to start with).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have up to 32 flags I need to test all at the same time, a BitVector32 is much more efficient:

```
if (bv & 0X...) ...
```

will test for several flags being "on".

```
if ((bv & 0X...) == 0) ...
```

tests for all the specified flags being off.

If I have a billion flags, I would rather play div and mod 32 to find which bitvector to use -- as opposed to using a lot of RAM.

(Actually, I would probably use a long or longlong, and not bother with `BitVector`.)

OTOH, for just a few flags, I would probably use the 1-byte thingies.  Wasteful of a few bytes, but faster.

And if I need yes/no/maybe, a single bit won't do.  (Ditto for M/F/...)